# Why does screen that gets arguments from ModalRoute re-build on Navigator pop?

Tags: flutter

I could not understand why my screen build was being executed when popping. I narrowed it down to this line:

```
    final String userId = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
```

Why does the screen rebuild? How should I stop it rebuilding, or bail out when it happens?

Here is a complete example, with counter-example:
https://dartpad.dev/9f83473a923e39e9c4b07840bc4aded7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be know by now, but no actual fixes have actually been found somehow (or so it seems).

- It is discussed here : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/63364
- As well as here : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/35575

Generally, the accepted solutions seem to either :

1. Pass the arguments to the page directly through parameters of the page class (see 'vivek yadav' answers).
2. Retrieve the arguments in the `initState()` method and directly inside `addPostFrameCallback()` (see code below) rather than in the `build()` or `didChangeDependencies()` methods.

```dart
@override
    void initState() {
        super.initState();
        WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
            final args = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
            print(args);
        });
}
```

However, I am still very interested to know if you found another solution or actual fix to this issue. Currently, I am using the 1st solution I listed above but I am not quite satisfied with it to be honest.

Comment: Sorry, I did not look further for a solution

Comment: No worries, thanks for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 0):

We pass a class object in MaterialPageRoute for eg

```
 Navigator.of(context).push(
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (ctx) => ScreenWithoutArg(),
                ),
              );
```

Sometimes, we need to send data while routing, also in some cases class is selected dynamically.
In such a scenario, If we add data implementation in class constructor then it's not a good coding practice.

Rather than we can pass the same data in RouteSettings.

// suggested

```
 Navigator.of(context).push(
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (ctx) => ScreenWithArg(),
                  settings: RouteSettings(arguments: 'Arg'),
           ),
         );
```

// not suggested (Prone to code changes)

```
 Navigator.of(context).push(
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (ctx) => ScreenWithArg(arg1: 'argdata',arg2:'agrdata2'),
                  settings: RouteSettings(arguments: 'Arg'),
           ),
        );
```

Thanks, @Patrick O'Hara for highlighting this stunning feature of the dart.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the benefits of using arguments. However, when the `ScreenWithArg` does `pop`, the `ScreenWithArg` `build` method is called, which is what I do not understand. This does not happen with `ScreenWithoutArg`.

Answer (score 0):

I dont get complatly your question but if you want to delete or pop before navigator

```
 Navigator.of(context).push(
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (ctx) => ScreenWithArg(),
                  settings: RouteSettings(arguments: 'Arg'),
                ),
              );
```

instead use this line code

```
 Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (ctx) => ScreenWithArg(),
                  settings: RouteSettings(arguments: 'Arg'),
                ),
              );
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is not my issue. When the `ScreenWithArg` does `pop`, the `ScreenWithArg` `build` method is called, which is what I do not understand. This does not happen with `ScreenWithoutArg`.